Generating pdf changes existing table layout
Here is the code which i am using to create pdf view when and specific cell is clicked in the table and when the generate method execute the size of the window shrinks open pdf view in new tab and again get back to normal why does this happens?
generatePDF(model: any) { 
        let pdf=new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');
        let htmlContent = this.test();
        pdf.html(htmlContent,{
            callback:(pdf)=>{
                pdf.output('dataurlnewwindow', { filename: 'file.pdf' }); 
            },x:10,y:10,width:580,windowWidth:800
        })
    }
    test(): string {
        return `
        <html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
           
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
        
        </head>
        <body>
            <style>
                body {
                    width: 100%;
                    max-width: 245mm;
                    min-height: 290mm;
                    margin: 0 auto;
                    border: 0px solid;
                    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
                }
        
                #collectionTable tr td {
                    text-align: center;
                    border: 1px solid black;
                    min-height: 0;
                    white-space: pre-wrap;
                    page-break-inside: avoid;
                    page-break-after: auto
                }
        
                #collectionTable {
                    border-collapse: collapse;
                    width: 100%;
                    font-size: 10pt;
                    page-break-inside: avoid;
                }
        
                .tableleft tr td {
                    text-align: left;
                }
        
                .tableleft tr th {
                    text-align: left;
                }
        
                .breakhere {
                    border-collapse: collapse;
                    page-break-before: always;
                }
                table.print-friendly tr td, table.print-friendly tr th {
                    page-break-inside: avoid;
                }
            </style>
        
            <div style="height:0px;"></div>
        
            <h2 style="text-align:center;">Lab Requisition Form</h2>
        
            <table cellpadding="5" class="table table-bordered tableleft">
                <tr>
                    <td><b>LRF ID</b>    : </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>PID Number</b>    : </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Name </b>    : </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Gender</b>    : </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Date of Birth </b>    : </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        
            <h2 style="text-align: left;">Part I : Specimen Collection Information</h2>
        
            <table class="table tableleft" style="page-break-inside:avoid !important; page-break-after:auto !important; overflow: hidden; display:block !important; width:100%;" cellpadding="5">
            </table>
        
            <h2 style="text-align: left;">Part II: Specimen Transport</h2>
        
            <table class="table tableleft" style="width:80%;" cellpadding="5">
            </table>
        
            <h2 style="text-align: left;">Part III: Specimen Receipt</h2>
        
       

     <table class="table tableleft" style="width:80%;" cellpadding="5">
            </table>
        
            <h2 style="text-align: left;">FOR LAB USE ONLY</h2>
        
            <table class="table" style="width:100%; font-size: 12px;" border="1" cellpadding="5">
            </table>
        
            <h2 style="text-align: left;">TRANSPORTATION DETAILS</h2>
        
            <table class="table" style="width:100%;" border="1" cellpadding="5">
            </table>
        </body>
        </html>
        `;
    }

I want to view pdf with the styling that is being used in test() method and opens in a new tab for view pdf(NOT DOWNLOAD) without affecting the existing data style
